# Automatic service skeleton generation from SwaggerAPI in python

Tags: python, flask, swagger

Is any tool that can take a SwaggerAPI specification and generate a service skeleton in python using flask (possibly including input checks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste your spec into https://editor.swagger.io and select **Generate Server > python-flask**.

The editor uses [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) for code generation. You can also install and use the [Swagger Codegen CLI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#prerequisites) locally if you wish.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-<VERSION>.jar generate
     -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
     -l python-flask
     -o .\python-flask-server
```

(The command above must be written as a single line.)